# Amazon EC2 using high bandwidth

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, akamai

I have a amazon ec2 instance, i figured out that my cost went high in 2-3 days, previously which were $375 and now they are $1545.

I have a PHP website with small number of users, storing data to amazon S3.

Below is the network usage.

This occurs when i run my php code to store data on amazon s3, i do not why akami is using bandwith. while i have not configured or used this.

what is akami doing on my server, is this some kind of spam? how can i stop akami on my server?

What is the reason of this? my instance hacked?

[image]

Comment: I have sent them a support ticket but they still have not replied.

Comment: you do realise that in almost all circumstances a dedicated server would be much much cheaper than "cloud" hosting.  Unless your site really requires the ability to burst and scale up through the roof there's little to no benefit in the type of hosting you're currently using.  For $100 a month you could easily get a dedi + a remote storage setup which would give you much more available processing power and bandwidth than the cloud based systems it just isn't as easy to burst or load balance if you require the extra capacity.

Comment: I worked out the cost to convert my cluster to amazon services and it would have pushed me above 100k a month rental at current it costs me 400 a month for the 5 dedicated servers

Comment: Are you using Akami as a CDN?

Comment: No I am noting Akami as a CDN i am using amazon S3.